# iOS Firebase Push notification not working on simulator with Xcode 11.5 and iOS 13

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I have tried for Firebase Push notification but its not working. Remote message is displaying on console with payload but not showing the notification on simulator. I using Xcode 11.5 and iOS 13.

1. added GoogleService-Info.plist to root folder
2. did all code required for Firebase Push notification
3. uploaded .p12 file on firebase console
4. added push notification capability on Xcode

Comment: Could you please provide a more detailed information?

Comment: I tried for getting push notification on simulator (Xcode 11.5 and iOS 13), I tried all ways but still something is missing. The message (payload) is displaying on console (using remoteMessage.appdata) but it's not showing on simulator. UNUserNotificationCenter is not working. while sending notification from firebase console only didReceiveMessage method is called not other methods.
Thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can follow [this article](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/testing-push-notification-on-ios-simulator-from-xcode-11-4-beta-2fdd91d67bff) for testing push notifications in the simulator. For testing remote notifications that is sent directly from firebase you will need a physical device. I am using xcode 11.6 and during the registration process it is showing a message in the console: `Error! iOS Simulator does not support push! Please test on a real iOS device. remote notifications are not supported in the simulator`

Here is the summary for testing push notification in simulator:

- Register for push notifications and make sure you allow it.
- Create a file named: `test_push_notification.apns`
- Add and save the following JSON in the newly created file just by replacing bundle identifier as per your app.
- { "Simulator Target Bundle": "com.yourapp.bundleid", "aps": { "alert": { "title": "Push on the simulator", "subtitle": "Test push notification", "body": "This notification will show up in the simulator!" } } }
- Open terminal and navigate to the directory where you saved the file.
- Run this command `xcrun simctl push booted test_push_notification.apns`

Comment: Thank you for your response, 

      I tried above solution but getting the error like, 

An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain, code=3840): The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format. The data is not in the correct format.

Comment: This message means system is unable to parse the json. Copy the correct json that i also posted in the answer.

Comment: here is may .apns file format,


{ 
"Simulator Target Bundle": "my projects bundle identifier",
 "aps": { 
 "alert": { 
   "title": "Push on the simulator", 
   "subtitle": "Test push notification", 
   "body": "This notification will show up in the simulator!" 
     }
    }
}